# Build ffmpeg for Windows with milliseconds support to overlay local timestamp onto video

Tags: ffmpeg, build

Using ffmpeg, I would like to overlay the current local timestamp with milliseconds onto a video using ffmpeg in a `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.mmm` format. I've seen a similar question asked, but did not see an answer to displaying millisecond portion.

Using `text=%{localtime}` simply displays `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` without milliseconds. If you try to use common millisecond specifiers to display the milliseconds portion it does not work as in `text=%{localtime\\:%Y %m %d %H %M %S %s}` or `text=%{localtime\\:%Y %m %d %H %M %S %f}`.

If you use `text=%{pts\\:hms}` it does display milliseconds, but it's not referenced to current local time. You could add an offset in total seconds since midnight to bring you get you close to the local time as in `text=%{pts\\:hms\\:61200}` to get you to 5pm, but that is a snapshot of when the command was called, not the actual current local time the video frame was captured in milliseconds.

#### UPDATE:

I just found this article: https://github.com/InSoundz/ffmpeg-strftime-milliseconds
It looks like someone had added millisecond resolution to the `strftime()` function that ffmpeg uses.

My only issue is I do not know how to re-build the Windows release *.exe using this source code. Can anyone assist with this? Once that is re-built into a Windows executable, then I should be able to add millisecond resolution using a `%u` formatter as in: `%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.%%03u` to get the example of `2017-05-28_12-26-33.599` timestamp added to the recorded video. Could anyone please assist me with this Windows *.exe re-build using this modified library?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here is some documentation on compiling ffmpeg - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide#Windows and here's a related question - https://superuser.com/questions/1425350

Answer (score 1):

From the [drawtext documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext):

> localtime
> The time at which the filter is running, expressed in the
> local time zone. It can accept an argument: a strftime() format
> string.

However, strftime does not have a function to display milliseconds. See [`man strftime`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html).

You used `%s` which is the, "number of seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC)". Not what you want. I'm not sure where you found `%f`, but it's not valid for strftime.

Comment: Thanks for the info - agreed - hopefully someone has an idea of how to gain the localtime with millisecond resolution to add to the recoded video!

Comment: @svojoe I know it wasn't the answer you were looking for but unfortunately I do not have an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - if you read my 'UPDATE' within my original question - it looks  like someone has already created a updated strftime() function with milliseconds added for use with ffmpeg - I just need assistance with re-building ffmpeg for a windows *.exe release using the updated function - I have no experience with this... The current Windows *.exe autobuilds for download do not include this updated strftime() function.

Comment: @svojoe That's 4 years old so probably won't apply to the current codebase and it appears to have been implemented just for the segment muxer output file name. I don't use Windows so I won't be much help there.