# Why does FFmpeg default to libvorbis?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, aac, vorbis

Despite having used it for years, I very recently learnt (or maybe relearnt) that FFmpeg encodes by default even when not asked to, unless the streams are explicitly passed through with `-c copy`.

This led me to use `ffprobe` to check the codec of a video I recently encoded using minimal parameters, and I now realise the video was encoded with `x264` and audio with `libvorbis`.

`x264` is unsurprising since it's the current video standard, but `libvorbis` surprises me given that the [FFmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/HighQualityAudio) ranks it lower than `libopus` and `libfdk_aac`:

```
libopus – usable range ≥ 32Kbps. Recommended range ≥ 64Kbps
libfdk_aac default AAC LC profile – recommended range ≥ 128Kbps; see AAC Encoding Guide.
libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he_v2 – usable range ≤ 48Kbps CBR. Transparency: Does not reach transparency. Use AAC LC instead to achieve transparency
libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he – usable range ≥ 48Kbps and ≤ 80Kbps CBR. Transparency: Does not reach transparency. Use AAC LC instead to achieve transparency
libvorbis – usable range ≥ 96Kbps. Recommended range -aq 4 (≥ 128Kbps)
libmp3lame – usable range ≥ 128Kbps. Recommended range -aq 2 (≥ 192Kbps)
ac3 or eac3 – usable range ≥ 160Kbps. Recommended range ≥ 160Kbps
libtwolame – usable range ≥ 192Kbps. Recommended range ≥ 256Kbps
mp2 – usable range ≥ 320Kbps. Recommended range ≥ 320Kbps
```

I [compiled my FFmpeg build](https://superuser.com/a/1425351/323079) with both `libopus` and `libfdk_aac`, so is there a reason the audio is defaulting to `libvorbis` here?

And is there a way to change these defaults to ensure FFmpeg will always use `libfdk_aac` (unless otherwise specified)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does FFmpeg default to libvorbis?

I'm assuming you output to Matroska (`.mkv`). You can see the defaults with:

```
ffmpeg -h muxer=matroska
  Muxer matroska [Matroska]:
    Common extensions: mkv.
    Mime type: video/x-matroska.
    Default video codec: h264.
    Default audio codec: vorbis.
    Default subtitle codec: ass.
```

If you don't know the exact name of your muxer see `ffmpeg -h muxers`.

Why libvorbis? It's what is listed first in `libavformat/matroskaenc.c`:

```
AVOutputFormat ff_matroska_muxer = {
    .name              = "matroska",
    .long_name         = NULL_IF_CONFIG_SMALL("Matroska"),
    .mime_type         = "video/x-matroska",
    .extensions        = "mkv",
    .priv_data_size    = sizeof(MatroskaMuxContext),
    .audio_codec       = CONFIG_LIBVORBIS_ENCODER ?
                         AV_CODEC_ID_VORBIS : AV_CODEC_ID_AC3,
    .video_codec       = CONFIG_LIBX264_ENCODER ?
                         AV_CODEC_ID_H264 : AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4,
```

Why libvorbis? It was changed to libvorbis from mp2 in 2011 with [matroskaenc: saner default codecs](https://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=3436c4a368aca1bdcbf28bdfc996903460263de0). Back then libvorbis was pretty good.

Why libvorbis 10 years later?

- Some users complain when things change.
- Some developers complain when things change.
- Perhaps nobody has submitted a patch to change it.
- There are more important or interesting things to work on.
- libopus is still kind of new.
- libfdk_aac will never be the default as it is non-free.

> And is there a way to change these defaults to ensure FFmpeg will always use libfdk_aac (unless otherwise specified)?

- Just use `-c:a libfdk_aac`
- or modify the source code and re-compile
- or submit a patch to change the defaults

Comment: Great FFmpeg answer as always. Does FFmpeg have a Github or is everything still on mailing lists? As for changing the source code and recompiling, is it likely to be just the one place it needs changing, or a few?

Comment: @HashimAziz Github is only used as a mirror. Development occurs on the ffmpeg-devel mailing list. Like the Linux kernel it is too big of a project to split the development into several places. For the source code you'll probably have to edit each muxer you're interested in.

Comment: *libopus is still kind of new.* --> It's over 13 years old. It's long been mature.